# Composition of two polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

How's to make the composition of two polynomials? According to [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial#Behavior_under_addition.2C_subtraction.2C_multiplication_and_function_composition):

If $ P = (x^3 + x) $, $ Q = (x^2 + 1) $ then,

$ P\circ Q = P\circ (x^2 + 1) = (x^2 + 1)^3 + (x^2 + 1) = x^6 + 3 x^4 + 4 x^2 + 2 $

It seems that the $ (x^3 + x) $ becomes the $x^3$, then we have $( \space \space \space )^3$ and now we just need to switch the inside of $P$ by the inside of $Q$ thus $(x^2 + 1)^3$.

I'm just not sure if my interpretation is correct. I'm also aware that I may not be using the right terms for describing this, but it's what I have now.

Comment: $x^3+x$ doesn't become $x^3$, it stays as $x^3+x$ and then you have $(\ )^3+(\ )$. :)

Comment: By definition $\: (P\circ Q)(x)\, =\, P(Q(x))\, =\, Q(x)^3 + Q(x)\ \ $

Comment: I remember of studying Sum of two polynomials, difference of two polynomials, product of a constant and a polynomial and product of two polynomials. They kinda make sense for me, where is compostion of two polynomials useful?

Comment: Ah, Another question: Is composition used only on polynomials with two constants? The given examples show me only operations on polynomials such as $(x^3 + x)$ but I've seen no references to polynomials with 3 constants such as $(x^3 + 4x^2 - x)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks fine. Maybe it becomes even clearer, when you write it like:
$$
P\circ Q = (x^3 + x)\circ Q= (Q^3+Q)=(x^2 + 1)^3 + (x^2 + 1) = x^6 + 3 x^4 + 4 x^2 + 2
$$

Comment: You again, Draks? May our friendship last forever, While I'm studying mathematics, I'll ask a lot. Any doubt about our friendship? Axiom 1: There is a friendship between draks and GustavoB such that draks answers GustavoB's noob questions.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira Thanks, but don't expect too much, I'm not even a mathematician. The time will come when you answer my questions. Good luck for your studies...

Comment: Well. I can't even sum 2 integers - But I guess I can odd sum 2 integers. You're higher on the hierarchical tree - considering it exists.